# Send Bundle to calling activity

Tags: android

I have two Activities in my app, a "Main" and a "Prompt" Activity. The Prompt is called from a button on the ActionBar in the Main Activity, and the Prompt has several EditText objects and a Spinner. The Prompt also has a Button that, when pressed, should validate the values in these objects and then send them back to the Main Activity.

I know you can send this information as a Bundle by placing it in an Intent and calling StartActivity. However, if I understand the Activity lifecycle, doing a startActivity() call to start the Main Activity will keep the old version of Main on the backstack and take up unneeded resources, as well as make it possible for the user to "clear" back to Prompt and then to the old Main Activity as well.

I want both the old Main activity as well as the Prompt activity to be removed from the backstack while also sending the values from Prompt's fields to a new Main activity. Can anyone help me figure out the most ideal way to accomplish this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this would be to start `Prompt` with `startActivityForResult()` then return the values to `onActivityResult()`

[Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html) with example

If for some reason this won't work for you then you can probably find an `Intent flag` that will accomplish what you need depending on your situation. One that may work for you is [FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT) This will bring your `MainActivity` to the top of the stack

Also, as long as you call `finish()` on your `PromptActivity` after calling `startActivity` then it will be cleared from the stack

You should watch [Google I/O Navigation](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XwGHJJYBs0Q). It explains navigation and how the stack works very well

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm going to try it right away and report my results.

Comment: You're welcome. Hope it works. See my edit about clearing `Prompt` and I will post a link shortly that may be helpful

Comment: Actually I can't tell you yet because another insidious, annoying error has popped up. I keep getting a "java.lang.IllegalStateException" followed by a "java.lang.NullPointerException" when I try this line in my code: `String text = paymentEt.getText().toString();`. The weird thing is that I continued to get this error on the same line after I commented it out! Something is very, very wrong.

Comment: If you are getting it on a line that is commented out then you need to clean your project and rebuild it. Eclipse didn't recognize the change yet or you haven't saved it

Comment: Oh my goodnight, can't believe I forgot to try that. Running a clean now. My netbook is huffing and puffing to keep up, so I'll post again and let you know how it went. Thanks again for the suggestion!

Comment: No problem. Let me know if that doesn't help

Comment: Okay...not sure if it's my netbook being slow (don't think so) but now I'm getting 34 errors saying "R cannot be resolved to a variable". I've run into this error before (not frequently) so I tried to fix project properties too, but those errors aren't going away. Any thoughts?

Comment: You need to be sure that you don't have any errors in ANY xml files, including `manifest`, be sure you are importing your projects .R file and not android.r, then look in `gen` folder. If there is an android.R then remove it and your projects .R file should be regenerated. Maybe have to clean again

Comment: Actually, got it. I updated the SDK to version 22 but apparently needed to download a new item, Android Build Tools. It's downloading now, that should fix the build errors, then I'll let you know how your solution worked. Finally. :)

Comment: And we are GOOD! Your answer to my original question worked like a charm. Thank you so much!